# How to use Terraform Plan and Apply in different Jenkins pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am working on a declarative Jenkins pipeline for Terraform deployments. I want to have the terraform init / select workspace / plan in one stage, ask for approval in another stage, and then do the apply in another stage. I have the agent at the top set to none and then using a kubernetes agent for a docker image we created that has packages we need for the stages. I am declaring those images in each stage. When I execute the pipeline, I get an error that I need to reinitialize Terraform in the apply stage even though I initialized in the init/plan stage. I figure this is nature of the stages running in different nodes.

I have it working by doing init / plan and stashing the plan. In the apply stage, it unstashes the plan, calls init / select workspace again, and then finally applies the unstashed plan.

I realize I could set the agent at the top, but according to Jenkins documentation, that is bad practice, as waiting for user input will block the execution.

I feel like there has to be a way to do this more elegantly. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
def repositoryURL = env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl != null && env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl != "" ? env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl : env.RepoURL
def repositoryBranch = env.gitlabTargetBranch != null && env.gitlabTargetBranch != "" ? env.gitlabTargetBranch : env.RepoBranch
def notificationEmail = env.gitlabUserEmail != null && env.gitlabUserEmail != "" ? env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl : env.Email
def projectName = env.ProjectName
def deployAccountId = env.AccountId

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Checkout") {
            agent any
            steps {
                git branch: "${repositoryBranch}", credentialsId: '...', url: "${repositoryURL}"
                stash name: 'tf', useDefaultExcludes: false
            }
        }
        stage("Terraform Plan") {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    label 'myagent'
                    containerTemplate {
                        name 'cis'
                        image 'docker-local.myrepo.com/my-image:v2'
                        ttyEnabled true
                        command 'cat'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                container('cis') {                    
                    unstash 'tf'
                    script {                                                      
                        sh "terraform init"

                        try {
                            sh "terraform workspace select ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}"
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sh "terraform workspace new ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}"
                        }

                        sh "terraform plan -out=${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}_plan.tfplan -input=false"

                        stash includes: "*.tfplan" name: "tf-plan", useDefaultExcludes: false
                    }
                }
            }
            post{
                success{
                    echo "Terraform init complete"
                }
                failure{
                    echo "Terraform init failed"
                }
            }
        }
        stage ("Terraform Plan Approval") {
            agent none
            steps {
                script {
                    def userInput = input(id: 'confirm', message: 'Apply Terraform?', parameters: [ [$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: false, description: 'Apply terraform', name: 'confirm'] ])
                }
            }
        }
        stage ("Terraform Apply") {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    label 'myagent'
                    containerTemplate {
                        name 'cis'
                        image 'docker-local.myrepo.com/my-image:v2'
                        ttyEnabled true
                        command 'cat'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                container("cis") {
                    withCredentials([[
                        $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                        credentialsId: 'my-creds',
                        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                    ]]) {
                        script {
                            unstash "tf"
                            unstash "tf-plan"   

                            sh "terraform init" 
                            try {
                                sh "terraform workspace select ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}"
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                sh "terraform workspace new ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}"
                            } 

                            sh """
                               set +x
                               temp_role="\$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/myrole --role-session-name jenkinzassume)" > /dev/null 2>&1

                               export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\$(echo \$temp_role | jq .Credentials.AccessKeyId | xargs) > /dev/null 2>&1
                                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\$(echo \$temp_role | jq .Credentials.SecretAccessKey | xargs) > /dev/null 2>&1
                                export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\$(echo \$temp_role | jq .Credentials.SessionToken | xargs) > /dev/null 2>&1
                                set -x

                               terraform apply ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}_plan.tfplan
                           """
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to run `init` again because your stash does not include the `.terraform/` folder.

Comment: Other that that, the usage of Terraform looks fine (or don't you need an `-auto-approve` for the `apply` step?

Comment: You can outout the tf plan and store it somewhere like

terraform plan -out tf.plan
And then apply like
terraform apply tf.plan